# Get Yoast WP SEO data by post ID

Tags: php, wordpress, yoast

Since there is no documentation about this, I was wondering in what way it is possible to get filtered Yoast WP SEO data (so not unfiltered `_yoast_wpseo` metadata) by given post ID.

Ideally, I would like to get the exact representation of the HTML output by the Yoast plugin, or a full set of data in a JSON object. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Untested idea: most of it runs on `wpseo_head` (hooked into `wp_head`). Turn on output buffering, make sure your postdata is setup up, and execute it.

```
ob_start();
do_action("wpseo_head");
$yoast = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Tried that! However, WP SEO resets the global $wp_query back to its original state, ensuring that the plugin always generates the correct HTML output for the current visited post.

Comment: You're right. You can manipulate that, though, by setting $wp_query to your own query and setting `$wp_query->is_singular = true`. You'll also have to reset their singleton: `WPSEO_Frontend::$instance = false` so it's reinstantiated. Unfortunately, you can only get certain values that way, others are cached & private. What exactly are you after?

Comment: I'm trying to add the data to either the WP Rest API, or an on_save POST request to an external database (such as mongo or Amazon DynamoDB). For both, the post ID is the only input I could use to generate that data. Alternative thought that I had, is to cURL the URL of the post and crawl SEO data out of the head tag, but that's not very straight forward either.

Comment: Mhh, it fails if its Frontend-Class (and the hooks attached to `wpseo_head`) ran already. But it shouldn't run on the Rest API nor in the backend, so manipulating $wp_query could work. Have you tried that, too?

Answer (score 1):

Use
`get_post_meta($postId, '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw')` and `get_post_meta($postId, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc')`

I found this question trying to get yoast data from a particular post (by ID) and came to this solution:

Made a function that recieves the post id

```
public static function postMetas($postId)
{
        $metas['keyword'] = get_post_meta($postId, '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw');
        $metas['description'] = get_post_meta($postId, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc');

        return $metas;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Today you can use : YoastSEO()->meta->for_post($postId)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35361150)